# ZIP and delete files older than 7 days using 7ZIP and CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, 7zip

I have about 20 000 files in the folder, I want to zip and delete files older than 7 days. I tried this script, but it works very slow:

```
Set TDate=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('
 forfiles /p C:\ARCHIVE /s /m *.txt /d -7 /c "cmd /c echo @path"
') do (
 "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "C:\ARCHIVE_%TDate%.zip" %%i
 del /a /f %%i
)
```

Please advise how to make it work faster.

Comment: This question belongs on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides usage of `forfiles` which is very slow (but inevitable for this script, I think), the main decelerating part of your script is the modification of the archive in every single loop iteration. Instead, you should do the archiving once only, perhaps using a list file, then let the archiving tool delete files it successfully compressed on its own:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=C:\ARCHIVE"
set "_PATTERN=*.txt"
set "_LIST=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
set "_ARCHIVER=%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe"

rem // Get current date in locale-independent format:
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%D in ('wmic OS get LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "TDATE=%%D"
set "TDATE=%TDATE:~,8%"

rem // Create a list file containing all files to move to the archive:
> "%_LIST%" (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
        forfiles /S /P "%_ROOT%" /M "%_PATTERN%" /D -7 /C "cmd /C echo @path"
    ') do echo(%%~F
) && (
    rem // Archive all listed files at once and delete the processed files finally:
    "%_ARCHIVER%" a -sdel "%_ROOT%_%TDATE%.zip" @"%_LIST%"
    rem // Delete the list file:
    del "%_LIST%"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Thank you, it works much faster (2 minutes instead of 7 hours)